# Specifying multiple address spaces for a type in the list of arguments of function

Tags: opencl

I wrote a function in OpenCL:

```
void sort(int* array, int size)
{
}
```

and I need to call the function once over a `__private` array and once over a `__global` array. Apparently, it's not allowed in OpenCL to specify multiple address spaces for a type. Therefore, I should duplicate the declaration of function, while they have exactly the same body:

```
void sort_g(__global int* array, int size)
{
}

void sort_p(__private int* array, int size)
{
}
```

This is very inefficient for maintaining the code and I am wondering if there is a better way to manage multiple address spaces in OpenCL or not?

**P.S.:** I don't see why OpenCL doesn't allow multiple address spaces for a type. Compiler could generate multiple instances of the function (one per address space) and use them appropriately once they're called in the kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For OpenCL < 2.0, this is how the language is designed and there is no getting around it, regrettably.
- For OpenCL >= 2.0, with the introduction of the *generic address space*, your first piece of code works as you would expect.

In short, upgrading to 2.0 would solve your problem (and bring in other niceties), otherwise you're out of luck (you could perhaps wrap your function in a macro, but ew, macros).